# Problem displaying parameters in the Azure Deovps test report

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, testing, azure-devops

Problem Description:
I am encountering an issue while running automated Selenium tests in Azure DevOps. The tests are running with various parameters, and they display correctly in Visual Studio. However, when viewing the results in Azure DevOps, it appears as though the tests are executed with only a single parameter.

Details:
The test names are correctly formatted in Visual Studio as "TestName(UsedParameter)" with a total of 5 different parameters.
The issue seems to be related to the display of test results in Azure DevOps, rather than the execution of tests.
The actual execution of tests appears to be fine, and they run with the expected parameters.
Code:

Test:

```
[DataTestMethod, TestCategory("Settings")]
[DataRow(UserRoleNames.SystemAdministrator)]
[DataRow(UserRoleNames.Administration)]
[DataRow(UserRoleNames.ProjectManager)]
[DataRow(UserRoleNames.SalesManager)]
[DataRow(UserRoleNames.Worker)]
public async Task Settings_ChangeLanguage(UserRoleNames userRoleName)
```

UserRoleNames:

```
public enum UserRoleNames
    {
        SystemAdministrator,
        ProjectManager,
        Worker,
        Administration,
        SalesManager
    }
```

What I've Tried:

- I have verified that the test configuration in Visual Studio is
  correct and displays the parameters properly.
- I suspect that the problem may be related to how Azure DevOps
  interprets and displays the test results.

[Azure test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOCNy.png)

Request for Assistance:
I am seeking help in understanding why Azure DevOps is not displaying the test results with the correct parameter information. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into how to adjust the test result display in Azure DevOps, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Have you tried to export the pipeline selenium test result file, check it on local, will it show as expected? Also please check the doc [Review test results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Yes, after exporting to a file and running it locally, everything looks fine.

Comment: Did you check the test result file? For Vstest task, it will generate trx file, you can find details in pipeline log. You can use task [PublishTestResults@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-test-results-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=trx%2Ctrxattachments%2Cyaml) to publish the test result to summary page.  To let others who have the similar question with you know how you resolved it more clearly, you can post an reply and [mark it answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), thanks.